# How to prevent sending Origin HTTP header in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, http-headers, cors

Situation:

1. I have a production web server, let's say https://example.com, configured with CORS with limited set of allowed origins. The set does NOT include localhost origins.
2. On localhost, developers develop a page/module/whatever that needs to call the production web server via AJAX (even during development). To do that, they run Chrome with CLI arguments --disable-web-security --user-data-dir=chromeNoCors so that Chrome would send AJAX without Origin header.
3. The problem is that only GET requests are sent without the header. POST requests still contain the header, therefore the production server compares the header value (http://localhost:5678) with allowed set of origins and forbids access to requested resource.

Question:
Is it possible to somehow prevent sending of Origin HTTP header altogether?

I'm aware that there's a workaround to solve this situation by allowing "localhost" (or some specific host that developers will have to add to their /etc/hosts) to the set of allowed origins on production server but I'd like not to do this if possible.

Comment: "On localhost, developers develop a page/module/whatever that needs to call the production web server via AJAX (even during development)" — Sounds like you are trying to hack around having an dev environment that isn't up to the job. You should fix *that* problem instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you guys use chrome try this extension
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/requestly-redirect-url-mo/mdnleldcmiljblolnjhpnblkcekpdkpa

you can modify requests on the fly,even headers

Comment: Thank you, this works very well and is really simple to setup, which is what I need, so I'll accept this as the answer. In general, using proxy would be probably more robust way.

Comment: @Lorenzo Requestly developer here. Requestly works for Firefox as well. Checkout http://www.requestly.in

Answer (score 3):

I recommend that you setup a simple "proxy server" (short node.js or python script would suffice). Have this server forward all requests to your remote API server but delete the information about the origin in headers. This is a matter of simple regular expression.

This is simple solution that will be portable to different servers. On AJAX side, all you need is to change the hostname to localhost or IP of your testing proxy server.

Comment: Yes, using reverse proxy would work, if all URLs used were under my control so that I could change them to go to localhost. In my case, some of the modules used from production web server however could use hard-coded URLs which would make them non-functional.

Comment: Using normal (non-reverse) proxy is actually a solution too and would work across browsers and also for mobile devices, but is not entirely simple for setup because of https. Proxy would act as MITM, would have to have self-signed certificate which should be either installed as trusted or a developer would have to accept exception every time; browser must be configured to use the proxy; there might be issues with HSTS Key Pinning (probably need to be removed too).

Comment: First, afaik local proxy servers have no problems with HTTPS. But most importantly what I meant is that you should change target URL in client side scripts for the debugging process to the proxy server URL. Your code should be modular enough to be able to do that. Any hardcoded urls coming from the remote server can be changed by the proxy script.